# golang too many open files in go function, goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1024 * 1024)
    for i := 0; i < (1024 * 1024); i++ {
        go func(index int) {
            if f, e := os.Open(i); e == nil {
                //blah blah
                f.Close()
            }
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

If you run the program brings up the following error.
"open $ too many open files"
Please tell us how to eliminate the error.

Comment: the answer is not go related, but read the man page for `ulimit`. However - a. you code has two disastrous bugs, see if you can spot them.  And b. on top of that, you are trying to open 1M files at once, unless you have a massive RAID array this is not practical.

Comment: What is your OS, is it Unix/Linux?

Comment: ulimit is not the best solution. I would prefer to have only limited number of goroutines, that open files and process it (maybe 500 parallel opened files). And each goroutine should select inputs from same channel, opens the file, read and close it, and sent result back to other channel. This second channel should be a part of request. And everybody who needs to use such goroutine should create this channel, sent request and wait for result. Do you understand, or you need an example?

Answer (score 14):

You are running out of system resources because you are using up too many file descriptors without releasing enough of them. You need to limit concurrency in your program.

For this, you can have a buffered channel that acts as a counting semaphore.

```
// 12 is the maximum number of 
// concurrent processes that may run at any time.
// This number can be any value suitable as per platform.
// It could be set to runtime.NumCPU() as well.
sem := make(chan struct{}, 12)
```

Now you can modify your method as:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1024 * 1024)

    for i := 0; i < (1024 * 1024); i++ {
        go func(index int) {
            
            // if there are already 12 goroutines running, below send will block
            // and a new file wont be open
            sem <- struct{}{}

            // once this goroutine finishes, empty the buffer by one
            // so the next process may start (another goroutine blocked on
            // above send will now be able to execute the statement and continue)
            defer func() { <-sem }()

            // wg.Done must be deferred after a read from sem so that
            // it executes before the above read
            defer wg.Done()

            if f, e := os.Open(strconv.Itoa(index)); e != nil {
                // handle file open failure
                return
            }
            defer f.Close()
            // handle open file
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(sem)
}
```

Your use of `wg.Done` is also incorrect. Read about it [here](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

(Note that this code is to give a basic idea about this kind of problem. You can also refer to this question for a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817122/go-worker-pool-with-repetitive-queue-structure

Comment: This still has the two bugs of the original question: 1. the goroutine function refers to `i` and not to `index`which is passed to it, and will result in opening the wrong files (besides the fact that you can't open integers as files). 2. still adding 1024*1024 to the waitGroup while doing `Done()` just once :)

Comment: Updated the `index` bug. Thanks. About the `wg.Done`, what do you mean it's being done only once? Each goroutine only needs to do it once and that's what's happening. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: no it's ok, you fixed it.the code in the question itself has this bug.

Comment: Why is the thread limit set at 12? Where does this number come from?