# 'Too many open files' in Golang without opening any files

Tags: multithreading, go, file-io, concurrency

I have some go code for walking a directory, and it fails with `panic: fcntl: too many open files` when run. The issue is, as far as I'm aware, I haven't opened any files (and don't have any File objects I can call .Close() on).

```golang
package main

import (
  "sync"
  "io/ioutil"
  "path"
)

func walk (cfg config) {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup

  wg.Add(1)
  go processDir(cfg.fromDir, "", &wg, cfg)

  wg.Wait()
}

// path, relative path, waitGroup, config
func processDir (pth string, relPth string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, cfg config) {
  defer wg.Done()

  flInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir(pth)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  for _, f := range flInfo {
    var fPath = f.Name()
    var isDir = f.IsDir()

    if cfg.shouldIgnore(fPath) {
      continue
    }

    wg.Add(1)

    var newAbs = path.Join(pth, fPath)
    if isDir {
      var newRel = path.Join(relPth, fPath)
      go processDir(newAbs, newRel, wg, cfg)
    } else {
      go processFile(newAbs, relPth, wg, cfg)
    }
  }
}

func processFile (pth string, relPth string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, cfg config) {
  defer wg.Done()

  // TODO: Process file
}
```

I'm wondering, does the `ioutil.ReadDir()` call open a file descriptor for the directory, and without limiting the number of goroutines, my program is reading too many directories at once?

This is my first time using goroutines, so any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Directories are just special files.

Comment: ReadDir opens the directory and reads it. If you're calling too many ReadDir's simultaneously, you may run into file descriptor limit problems.

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of investigation, I fixed the issue using the 'counting semaphore' pattern in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38825523/7674702

I'm not sure if that means this question is a duplicate, because the issue is very similar but not quite the same.

Comment: An answer should include the solution to the problem, not just a link.